# Can Journey Builder be used to send an email three days prior to a dynamic date?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

We are setting up a journey that will send to multiple contacts with different date stamps.
A start dat, and and end date, We want to send a message three days prior to the end date.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: i would argue, yes. but decide for yourself: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331162/1-hour-reminders-for-events-in-marketing-cloud/331188#331188

Comment: Is Journey Builder a requirement? Or do you just need to send a single email, automatically?