# Is it possible to skip an email send if the "Wait until date/time" has passed in a Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are building a Journey in Marketing Cloud that has a linear set up with regards to emails being sent:

1. Day 1 - 1st of the month at 6am
2. Day 2 - 2nd of the month at 6am
3. Day 3 - 3rd of the month at 6am, etc.

We are using the `Wait Until Date Activity` in a Journey, before the `Email Send Activity` to create the above flow.

Is it possible to set up the Journey so that, if a subscriber joined on a subsequent Day they would jump straight to that Day Email, and NOT receive any of the previous Day Emails, for example:

1. Day 1 email sent out at 6am to 20 subscribers
2. 21st subscribers enters Journey at 7am on Day 1. They do not receive the Day 1 email.
3. Day 2 email sent out at 6am to 21 subscribers

In layman's terms, I believe I'm looking for a way to link the `Wait Until Date Activity` and `Email Send Activity` in a Journey, as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if I fear that I am repeating myself. :) I do believe this kind of usecase is easier to set up and maintain in a recursive way with dynamic emails instead of trying to go crazy on the journey dashboard, see here. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331162/1-hour-reminders-for-events-in-marketing-cloud/331188#331188

Comment: That looks like a very interesting read and one that I'm going to make a cup of coffee to tackle - thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still interested but the way I would "skip" is by finding some common denominator for those that are entering the journey after the intitial activation and using that as a Decision Node to then "skip" the first email activity and join on the second. In our case it was things like "DateCreated" for the contact, the date of when a certain checkbox was marked, and so on. So you make sure this is in the Data Extension firstly and then you can use it for the Decision Split :)